# Enable 4x MSAA using shell/ADB

Tags: adb, graphics

I have various Android devices, **rooted**, with version ranging from Android 4.1 to Android 6.0. I want to enable 4x MSAA using shell/ADB.

The code below is used to enable Hardware Overlay through a shell script

```
service call SurfaceFlinger 1008 i32 1
```

But is there a way to enable 4x MSAA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command:

```
adb shell setprop debug.egl.force_msaa true
```

To disable, replace `true` with `false`.

Tested on OnePlus 6 running Android 10.

Comment: You are awesome!!! It works in all versions of android. At least from 4.1.2 to 10